# Chrome extension that extracts automatically some data and displays them to the user

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

What i want to do is to create an extension for chrome that

1. will be active only when the user browse specific pages.
2. the main task will be when the coursor is hovering over a link, a number will appear next to the cursor.
3. that number will be extracted from the page's source code of the link

any suggestions on how i could do that? thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html and http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions. 2. JavaScript is the only relevant language in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You should do a content script, triggered by the specific pages.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Chrome injects automatically your content script in pages matching the pattern you indicate in manifest.json:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

The content script lets you interact with the page's DOM, thus you can find the anchors ( tags).  You may hang a listener from mouseover event, or you can just write the anchors **title** attribute (the text that popup when hoovering).

If your specific pages list isn't static (you want to modify the list without modifying the extension), then you may want to learn about programatic injection.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

If you choose to hang a listener, use addListener, don't use the mouseover attribute, because your listener function isn't in the same **world**, it's on an **isolated world**.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, i'm working on it, once i have some results i will post the code and give more details about what i try to achieve